# FeathersJS update trigger on create

Tags: feathersjs

I am trying to find the best way to update a value in another service after the creation of data, essentially how a trigger would work in a database context.  For instance I have an objects:

```
foo= {
  _id,
  barID, 
  otherData
}
bar= { 
  _id,
  newestFooID,
  otherData
}
```

When a new foo object is created I want update bar to link to the new object.  Is the only way to do this through a third service?  or is there someway to get enough use an after hook (the id field for foo is not available on create)?

I am trying to avoid using events, avoid rewriting the generated service data, and make it database independent (right now it is using mongoose, but that can/will change in the future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem!  The issue is because the hook.result is a mongoose object and not a different object.  The mongoose object didn't have the requisite field in it. While working on another problem I cam across the feathers mongoose hook "toObject()" which when called makes the result a javascript object with all the data I need in it.

Comment: I guess this what fixed it a newer update as well where lean: true is default.

Answer (score 2):

The id for `foo` should be available in an `after` hook for `create`. Then you can just `patch` the `bar` service accordingly:

```
app.service('foo').after({
  create(hook) {
    const barId = hook.result.barId;
    const newestFooId = hook.result._id;

    // Update the barId with the newestFooId
    return app.service('bar')
      .patch(barId, { newestFooId })
      .then(() => hook);
  }
});
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work, the "_id" field never showed up in result after create for whatever reason, I hacked around it by adding another ID field that was set in a pre-foo hook which did end up in the result field, not sure what is going on.